# append any line that starts with <br> with the previous line in whole document

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-editor

I wanna remove spaces and join line that starts with specific words at the last of previous line.

Example
From

```
`<b>any thing that matters<b> what ever, i don't know.
      <font=any type> what ever you do is not right<font>
      <br>this line will go to the end of above line
      <Hi>not this one<hi>
      <br>but this one
      <go>i hope you understand<go>`
```

To

```
`<b>any thing that matters<b> what ever, i don't know.
      <font=any type> what ever you do is not right<font><br>this line will go to the end of above line
      <Hi>not this one<hi><br>but this one
      <go>i hope you understand<go>`
```

I wanna do it with the help of commands as the files amount is huge.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one long file, you could open it with LibreOffice and work with search&replace, using regular expressions.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variant of the sed one-liner '40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign' from http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/ , replacing "=" with whatever character(s) you want to join on e.g. to join on whitespace followed by "< br >" something like

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n[[:space:]]*<br>/<br>/;ta' -e 'P;D' <yourfile>
```

should work

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver it is working for few files but not for all, i am working on the expression. Thanks a lot.